# Android TabHost Syntax

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I'm very new to developing on Android and the Java language in general and I can't seem to find an explanation on why the following statement has "(TabHost)" after the "=":

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
```

as opposed to:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

They do the same thing, right?  Why use either of them?  Also, please explain the syntax of the first code specifically, please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case returns a generic `View`, which is the superclass from which all other views inherit. You have to *cast* it to a `TabHost` since Java doesn't know it's supposed to be one. It translates to saying "get me the View with this id, which, by the way, is supposed to be a TabHost".

The second instance is a method that is part of the `TabActivity` class which specifically returns a `TabHost` object, so there's no need for casting.

Comment: So in the first example `findViewById(R.id.tabHost)` finds the `View` `tabHost` and casts it to the `TabHost` type via the `(TabHost)` and assigns it to the variable `tabHost`?  I would think that the type declaration for the variable `tabHost` would inform Java that `findViewById(R.id.tabHost)` should be a `TabHost`.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured out why I was initially confused.  The first instance was from a tutorial that was creating tabs that loaded different `View`s into `tabContent` and the second is from a Google tutorial that extends `TabActivity` so that `intent`s can be used to fill `tabContent` with different `Activity`s.

The first instance creates a `TabHost` object from a `View` and the second uses a method in `TabActivity` to create a `TabHost` object, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. In the first example the developer was just providing a Layout with a TabHost in a normal Activity, so he had to cast that view. The second example they could use the `getTabHost()` convenience function. Note that this convenience function ends up doing the same casting song and dance, in an albeit more convoluted fashion. You can check out TabActivity's source code [here](http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/TabActivity.java), look inside the `onContentChanged()` method.